# How to sort by count on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am doing a group-by operation, counting the number of entries on each group. Here is the code:

```
db.feeds.group({key:{link:1, 'subtitle_detail.base':1}, reduce:function(curr,result){
        result.count++
    },
    initial: {count: 0}
    })
```

This code returns an array. how do I modify the code so that the array is sorted in descending order, by count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) instead of group(), you can achieve this easily using an additional sort phase in the pipeline:

```js
db.feeds.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:{link:"$link", base:"$subtitle_detail.base"}, 
        count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{count:1}}
])
```

Comment: I Like this solution! not only it is shorter, but it is also almost 10x faster! What I don't like about this syntax is that you have to create this _id: instead of simply passing the keys as is usual in other operation in Mongo.

Comment: The aggregation framework's syntax might be a little confusing in the beginning, but once you get a hang of it, it is quite straightforward and elegant.  Also, the framework is quite powerful enabling us to write rich queries.  If the answer solved your question, you should consider accepting the solution :)

Comment: i think in general aggregation is faster than map reduce

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large number of documents, sort will run out of memory.  If that happens, you can tell the pipeline to sort on disk rather than in memory by adding the option allowDiskUse:

```
db.feeds.aggregate([
    {$group:{
        _id:{link:"$link", base:"$subtitle_detail.base"}, 
        count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{count:1}}
],
{allowDiskUse: True})
```